# Train-Test split for Time Series Data to be used for LSTM

Tags: time-series, regression, lstm, training

```
values = df.values
train, test = train_test_split(values)

#Split into train and test
X_train, y_train = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
X_test, y_test = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
```

Executing the above code splits the time series dataset into training- 70% and testing 30%. I want to control the train-test split as 80-20 or 90-10. **Can someone please help me understand what train[:, :-1] does in this context?**

It is borrowed from https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/.

Note : **I cannot split the dataset randomly for train and  test and the most recent values have to be for testing**. I have included a screenshot of my dataset.

[image]If anyone can interpret the code, please do help me understand the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax `arr[:,:-1]` selects all rows and every column except the last one. Python can use negative indexing, but it's inclusive-exclusive such as `[a,b)`: inclusive of `a`, exclusive of `b`.

If you don't use the `:` operator, such as `arr[:,-1]`, then it simply selects the entire last column.

So in the context of your example, the last column is the value to be regressed/classified/etc according to the previous columns training data.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.random.randn(5,5)
>>> print(arr)
[[-0.86690967 -0.63959234  0.99754053 -0.24828822  0.5346927 ]
 [ 0.6174709   2.16558841 -1.28983554  1.15387215  0.64630439]
 [ 0.35104248 -0.54240157  0.80377977 -0.9447689  -0.08145433]
 [ 0.61195442  0.09407687  0.39065215 -0.8887228  -1.63845254]
 [-1.58212796 -0.46017275 -0.2065184   0.44879872 -0.95037541]]
>>> print(arr[:,:-1])
[[-0.86690967 -0.63959234  0.99754053 -0.24828822]
 [ 0.6174709   2.16558841 -1.28983554  1.15387215]
 [ 0.35104248 -0.54240157  0.80377977 -0.9447689 ]
 [ 0.61195442  0.09407687  0.39065215 -0.8887228 ]
 [-1.58212796 -0.46017275 -0.2065184   0.44879872]]
>>> print(arr[:,-1])
[ 0.5346927   0.64630439 -0.08145433 -1.63845254 -0.95037541]
```

Notice that the final print is actually the last column of `arr`, but because it is a 1D array, it appears as a row-vector rather than column-vector.